# Where is my TeamCity NuGet API Key stored?

Tags: nuget, teamcity

I want to publish to my TeamCity (v9) NuGet (v2.83) feed, using the TeamCity Publish build step.

But it is asking for the API key which no one knows?

I have seen %teamcity_nuget_api_key_1234567890123% TeamCity parameter about, but it didn't seem to work?

I do not have admin access to TeamCity, so it may be on a page I cannot see.

Can anyone help?

EDIT for clarity:
I am using TeamCity as my NuGet Server.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using TeamCity as your NuGet server? Rather than publishing to nuget.org?

Comment: Yes I am using the TeamCity as my NuGet Server.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you're using the internal TeamCity NuGet feed, you don't need to use the NuGet Publish build step; simply use NuGet Pack and choose to publish them as build artifacts.  This will automatically publish them on the internal feed.  Alternatively, if you have already created packages by some other means, you can simply publish them as build artifacts using [General Settings -> Artifact Paths](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+General+Settings#ConfiguringGeneralSettings-ArtifactPaths).

If you're trying to publish to an external feed, such as nuget.org, then the API key is externally managed and you'll need to 1) locate the API key from whoever manages the subscription to the feed, and 2) plug it into your build configuration.

Lots of information available [in the online doco](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/NuGet).

Comment: Thanks @SteveChapman. I would like to use the Publish step as I am using AutoPackage (from http://coapp.org/reference/autopackage-ref.html) to create the package (Native C++ type). Autopackage produces the finished pkg file, but does not leave me a nuspec file to use for the pack. As a workaround I unzip the pkg file and then Pack that. But it feels clunky. If thought if I had the API key I could skip unzipping and just publish.

Comment: In that case you should just be able to publish the initial nupkg file as a build artifact and it should be available on the feed.

Comment: Ooooo! hadn't thought of that. Great idea @SteveChapman ! Just tested it and works great. Thank you very much.